# Cómo hacer que android se conecte a mi servidor AMP

Tags: php, android, apache

Estoy intentando hacer un login en mi aplicación android a un servidor que tengo en mi casa con xampp. La cuestión es que ya le he dado permisos de conexión a internet y he implementado la conexión con el servidor, pero android me devuelve un error al intentar acceder a mi IP pública (me estoy conectando desde fuera de casa).

Les pongo el código:

```
package com.boredaf.kikasso.otheraplicationboredaf;


import android.os.AsyncTask;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;

import android.content.Intent;



public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toast prueba = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"se inicio",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);// creamos el mensaje
        prueba.show();

        Button botoncito= (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit);                                       //creamos un objeto de tipo botonm y lo bindeamos al submit del xml

        botoncito.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {                                   // cuando el boton sea presionado hara :
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                for(int i=0;i<30;i++){
                Toast prueba = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"se pulso el boton",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);// creamos el mensaje
                prueba.show();}
                //new AsyncLogin().execute();                                        // creamos un hilo de ejecucion secundario






                String username,password;                                                           // creamos variables strings para el usuario y la pass
                EditText usr = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);                              // creamos variables EditText y las bindeamos
                EditText pss = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passwd);
                username = usr.getText().toString();                                                // convertimos los EditText en Strings
                password = pss.getText().toString();

                Toast prueba = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"se pulso el boton",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);// creamos el mensaje
                prueba.show();
                try{
                    URL url = new URL("mi_ip/UserLogin.php");                                             // establecemos una url para la coneccion
                    HttpURLConnection urlConnection=(HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();            // inicializamos una coneccion a la url especificada
                    urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");                                             // indicamos que el metodo de coneccion sera de tipo post
                    urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);                                                    // indicamos que la coneccion podra traer info de salida (true)
                    /////////////////////////////////////// descifrar que cojones dice ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                    urlConnection.setDoInput(true);                                                     // indicamos que en la coneccion podremos recibir respuesta
                    urlConnection.setReadTimeout(10*1000);                                              // creamos un time out para la conecion
                    OutputStream outputStream = urlConnection.getOutputStream();                        // abrimos una conexión al recurso para poder enviar datos al formulario


                    BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter
                            (outputStream, "UTF-8"));


                    String post_data = URLEncoder.encode("username","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(username,"UTF-8")+"&"// El metodo encode() de URLEncoder se encarga
                            +URLEncoder.encode("password","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(password,"UTF-8"); //  de encodear la cadena que enviaremos al servidor, sustituyendo
                    //espacios y caracteres especiales

                    bufferedWriter.write(post_data);                                                    // metemos en un buffer los datos
                    // bufferedWriter.flush();          no hace falta ya que el close() hace flush       // hacemos que el buffer vomite los datos al servidor
                    bufferedWriter.close();                                                             // cerramos el buffer
                    outputStream.close();

                    InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();                           // abrimos una conexión al recurso para poder recibir la respuesta
                    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"iso-8859-1"));
                    String result="";
                    String line="";
                    while((line = bufferedReader.readLine())!= null) {
                        result += line;                                                                 // guarda la respeusta en result, este guarda mas informacion aparte de los echo , etc...
                    }

                    bufferedReader.close();
                    inputStream.close();
                    urlConnection.disconnect();


                    if(result.contains("confirmar")){                                                   // verificara si la cadena "confirmar" esta dentro de result
                        la_desicion_de_sophie(true);

                    }
                    else{

                        la_desicion_de_sophie(false);
                    }

                    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                }

                catch (MalformedURLException e) {                                                       // manejo de error en el caso de que la url no exista
                    Toast mensaje = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Error en la coneccion al servidor, la direccion no existe",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);// creamos el mensaje
                    mensaje.show();                                                                     // mostramos el mensaje
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                catch (IOException e) {                                                                 // manejo de error en el caso de que halla error en la conexion
                    Toast mensaje = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Error en la coneccion al servidor",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);                        // creamos el mensaje del error
                    mensaje.show();                                                                     // lo mostramos
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {


                }
            }
        });
    }
 private void la_desicion_de_sophie(boolean auth){

        if(auth){
            Intent goto_menu = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),main_app.class);
            startActivity(goto_menu);


        }
        else{
            TextView Error = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.error_msg);
            Error.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            //
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: hola perdonen, se me olvido decir, en el php hace la consulta sql , en caso de que la consulta tenga exito devuelve un "correcto",

Comment: Has comprobado que el servidor Xammp sea acesible des de fuera, comrpueba con el dispositivo en conectar a la ip etc.. normalmente viene cerrado

Comment: si, de hecho puedo conectarme desde el ordenador, mostrandome el index por defecto , que no lo he cambiado, pero aun asi especifico el archivo php al cual ir..., Tambien abri el puerto en el router

Comment: Mira en el log de android studio para ver que Htpp error te muestra, si muestra alguno

Comment: en donde veo eso  ?, soy nuevo en android studio ..

Comment: mira la documentación oficial de debuger: https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat.html?hl=es-419

Comment: Un error importante es que no estas definiendo una url correctamente:  URL url = new URL("mi_ip/UserLogin.php");  tu url debe usar el protocolo http:// o https://

Comment: vale probare incluyendo el http://, gracias

Comment: Acabo de probar lo del http://, me resolvio el problema, pero por alguna razon da error en el InputStream

Comment: ¿Sigues teniendo el problema en `InputStream` o lo solucionaste?

Comment: @k1k4ss0 he agregado una respuesta que podría explicarte el motivo de la excepción que sufres tras agregar `http://` a tu URL y cómo solucionarlo de dos maneras diferentes.

Answer (score 0):

Para que tu aplicación funcione he tenido que hacer dos modificaciones:

- Agregar esquema `http://` a la URL.
- Agregar permisos para permitir que la hebra principal (la de la interfaz de usuario) se bloquee en operaciones de red.

La primera es un error sencillo de arreglar y no afecta al rendimiento de la aplicación:

```
URL url = new URL("http://mi_ip/UserLogin.php");
```

## Permitiendo el bloque de UI con operaciones de red

El segundo problema requiere de una reestructuración del código más extensa para solucionarlo correctamente, aunque puede "parchearse" mediante el uso de [`StrictMode`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StrictMode.html) para permitir el bloqueo de la hebra de la interfaz de usuario por operaciones de red (que, en caso de no responder el servidor, podría bloquear aparentemente tu aplicación):

```
/* Permitir el bloqueo de la hebra principal en operaciones de red */
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
    .permitNetwork().build();
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

Además, te recomiendo cambiar la forma en la que montas los datos para mejorar su lectura de la siguiente manera:

```
String post_data = String.format("username=%s&password=%s",
    URLEncoder.encode(username,"UTF-8"),
    URLEncoder.encode(password,"UTF-8")
);
```

Tu código modificado queda:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    /* Permitir el bloqueo de la hebra principal en operaciones de red */
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
            .permitNetwork().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toast prueba = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"se inicio",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);// creamos el mensaje
    prueba.show();

    Button botoncito= (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit);                                       //creamos un objeto de tipo botonm y lo bindeamos al submit del xml

    botoncito.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {                                   // cuando el boton sea presionado hara :
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String username,password;                                                           // creamos variables strings para el usuario y la pass
            EditText usr = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);                              // creamos variables EditText y las bindeamos
            EditText pss = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passwd);
            username = usr.getText().toString();                                                // convertimos los EditText en Strings
            password = pss.getText().toString();

            Toast prueba = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"se pulso el boton",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);// creamos el mensaje
            prueba.show();
            try{
                URL url = new URL("http://mi_ip/UserLogin.php");                                             // establecemos una url para la coneccion
                HttpURLConnection urlConnection=(HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();            // inicializamos una coneccion a la url especificada
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");                                             // indicamos que el metodo de coneccion sera de tipo post
                urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);                                                    // indicamos que la coneccion podra traer info de salida (true)
                urlConnection.setDoInput(true);                                                     // indicamos que en la coneccion podremos recibir respuesta
                urlConnection.setReadTimeout(10*1000);                                              // creamos un time out para la conecion
                OutputStream outputStream = urlConnection.getOutputStream();                        // abrimos una conexión al recurso para poder enviar datos al formulario


                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter
                        (outputStream, "UTF-8"));
                String post_data = String.format("username=%s&password=%s",
                        URLEncoder.encode(username,"UTF-8"),
                        URLEncoder.encode(password,"UTF-8")
                ); //  de encodear la cadena que enviaremos al servidor, sustituyendo
                //espacios y caracteres especiales

                bufferedWriter.write(post_data);                                                    // metemos en un buffer los datos
                // bufferedWriter.flush();          no hace falta ya que el close() hace flush       // hacemos que el buffer vomite los datos al servidor
                bufferedWriter.close();                                                             // cerramos el buffer
                outputStream.close();

                InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();                           // abrimos una conexión al recurso para poder recibir la respuesta
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"iso-8859-1"));
                String result="";
                String line="";
                while((line = bufferedReader.readLine())!= null) {
                    result += line;                                                                 // guarda la respeusta en result, este guarda mas informacion aparte de los echo , etc...
                }

                bufferedReader.close();
                inputStream.close();
                urlConnection.disconnect();

                if(result.contains("confirmar")){                                                   // verificara si la cadena "confirmar" esta dentro de result
                    la_desicion_de_sophie(true);
                }
                else{
                    la_desicion_de_sophie(false);
                }

            }

            catch (MalformedURLException e) {                                                       // manejo de error en el caso de que la url no exista
                Toast mensaje = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        e.getLocalizedMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG);// creamos el mensaje
                mensaje.show();                                                                     // mostramos el mensaje
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (IOException e) {                                                                 // manejo de error en el caso de que halla error en la conexion
                Toast mensaje = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        e.getLocalizedMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG);                        // creamos el mensaje del error
                mensaje.show();                                                                     // lo mostramos
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
            }
        }
    });
}
```

## Forma correcta de realizar una tarea de red

La manera correcta de realizar tareas que pudieran bloquear la ejecución del programa es haciendo uso de hebras ([`Thread`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html)), [`Handler`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html), [`AsyncTask`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html), etc.

Como es muy común hacer uso de `Thread`, he preferido ponerte un ejemplo muy sencillo de `AsyncTask` porque éste te permite publicar resultados y avances en la hebra de interfaz de usuario en sus métodos `onProgressUpdate` y `onPostExecute` (aunque yo no lo haga en mi ejemplo).

La forma más sencilla de hacer el trabajo en segundo plano es:

```
new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... sinusar) {
        /* Trabajo a realizar */
    }
}.execute();
```

Aquí lo tengo integrado junto con tu código:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toast prueba = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"se inicio",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);// creamos el mensaje
    prueba.show();

    Button botoncito= (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit);                                       //creamos un objeto de tipo botonm y lo bindeamos al submit del xml

    botoncito.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {                                   // cuando el boton sea presionado hara :
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast prueba = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"se pulso el boton",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);// creamos el mensaje
            prueba.show();
            new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
                protected Void doInBackground(Void... sinusar) {
                    String username,password;                                                           // creamos variables strings para el usuario y la pass
                    EditText usr = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);                              // creamos variables EditText y las bindeamos
                    EditText pss = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passwd);
                    username = usr.getText().toString();                                                // convertimos los EditText en Strings
                    password = pss.getText().toString();
                    try{
                        URL url = new URL("http://mi_ip/UserLogin.php");                                             // establecemos una url para la coneccion
                        HttpURLConnection urlConnection=(HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();            // inicializamos una coneccion a la url especificada
                        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");                                             // indicamos que el metodo de coneccion sera de tipo post
                        urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);                                                    // indicamos que la coneccion podra traer info de salida (true)
                        urlConnection.setDoInput(true);                                                     // indicamos que en la coneccion podremos recibir respuesta
                        urlConnection.setReadTimeout(10*1000);                                              // creamos un time out para la conecion
                        OutputStream outputStream = urlConnection.getOutputStream();                        // abrimos una conexión al recurso para poder enviar datos al formulario


                        BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter
                                (outputStream, "UTF-8"));
                        String post_data = String.format("username=%s&password=%s",
                                URLEncoder.encode(username,"UTF-8"),
                                URLEncoder.encode(password,"UTF-8")
                        ); //  de encodear la cadena que enviaremos al servidor, sustituyendo
                        //espacios y caracteres especiales

                        bufferedWriter.write(post_data);                                                    // metemos en un buffer los datos
                        // bufferedWriter.flush();          no hace falta ya que el close() hace flush       // hacemos que el buffer vomite los datos al servidor
                        bufferedWriter.close();                                                             // cerramos el buffer
                        outputStream.close();

                        InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();                           // abrimos una conexión al recurso para poder recibir la respuesta
                        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"iso-8859-1"));
                        String result="";
                        String line="";
                        while((line = bufferedReader.readLine())!= null) {
                            result += line;                                                                 // guarda la respeusta en result, este guarda mas informacion aparte de los echo , etc...
                        }

                        bufferedReader.close();
                        inputStream.close();
                        urlConnection.disconnect();

                        if(result.contains("confirmar")){                                                   // verificara si la cadena "confirmar" esta dentro de result
                            la_desicion_de_sophie(true);

                        }
                        else{

                            la_desicion_de_sophie(false);
                        }

                    }

                    catch (MalformedURLException e) {                                                       // manejo de error en el caso de que la url no exista
                        Toast mensaje = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                e.getLocalizedMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG);// creamos el mensaje
                        mensaje.show();                                                                     // mostramos el mensaje
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    catch (IOException e) {                                                                 // manejo de error en el caso de que halla error en la conexion
                        Toast mensaje = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                e.getLocalizedMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG);                        // creamos el mensaje del error
                        mensaje.show();                                                                     // lo mostramos
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } finally {
                    }
                    return null;
                }
            }.execute();
        }
    });
}
```